# Is it possible to use a CSS wildcard in the middle of an attribute selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

I have some generated CSS and would like to use some css that could select e.g.

```html
<p id="loremIndexIpsum">Text in here</p>
```

Using on `lorem` and `Ipsum` disregarding `Index`. Something similar to:

```
p#lorem*Ipsum
{
}
```

I can generate some more classes, but wondered if this was possible with CSS.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can't use a wildcard like that, but to get the desired result (ID starts with `lorem` and ends with `Ipsum`) you can use the [attribute starts-with and ends-with selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) instead, like so:

```
p[id^="lorem"][id$="Ipsum"]
```

Remember that by linking multiple attribute selectors like this (along with the `p` type selector), you're doing an AND match with all of them on the same element.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vpZmq/1)

Comment: +1 didn't know about the starts-with and ends-with selector...now that I've learned my new thing for the day I can sleep til monday

Comment: Perfect! Got this working on the fiddle I was testing with: http://jsfiddle.net/DYnA3/3/

Comment: @StuperUser: I'd just cooked up my own fiddle with a few more tests as well; have at it!

Comment: Oh my lord, that is f******* amazing.

Comment: is there something like this, but with OR matching?

Comment: @törzsmókus: That would be just `p[id^="lorem"], p[id$="Ipsum"]`. Nothing fancy.

Comment: @BoltClock yes this is simple, unless you have a longer expression (then you have to repeat yourself a lot). I am also not sure whether it works when I have to provide exactly one CSS selector (for some 3rd party apps, that might depend on their implementation).

Comment: @törzsmókus: The only way to do it with a single compound selector (and without repetition) is with the as-yet-unimplemented :matches(): `p:matches([id^="lorem"], [id$="Ipsum"])`

Comment: I also found that you can do `p[id*='selector']`. Maybe it was introduced in a never version. I found it here: http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2011/06/selenium-css-selector-wildcard-example_16.html
@BoltClock maybe add this possibility as well?

Comment: @Bruno Bieri: That was introduced at the same time as these ones. The only reason I didn't mention it here is because it doesn't apply to this specific use case.

Comment: Google brought me here when I was looking for **wildcard**. I understand it's not applicable but now we have it at least in a comment ;-)