# CSS selector in JSF page not working

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, css-selectors

In a style section at the head of an xhtml page, I have the following CSS selector:

```
#form\:tabView\:tabExceptions {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

It works.

But when I try instead the following CSS selector (in the same location of the page):

```
[id$=tabExceptions] {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

It does not work.

Actually, even

```
[id=form\:tabView\:tabExceptions] {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

does not work.

Any idea why?

**My generated HTML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-admin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-blitzer" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-admin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/my-admin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/my-admin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/my-admin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery.corner.js?ln=js&amp;loc=en"></script>


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/css/default.css" />


<style>
/* <![CDATA[ */

.accordionPanel {
    width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.tabView {
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

/* div space between accordion tabs */
/*
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
}
*/

/* accordion tabs - upper space */
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header { margin-top: 50px; }

/* accordion tabs - uppermost tab */
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header.do-nothing { margin-top: 0; }

/***************************/
/* Rounded corners: */

.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    *border-collapse: collapse; /* Fallback for IE <=7. */
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0; border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:first-child th:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0; border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:first-child th:only-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tbody td {
    border-top: 0;
    *border-top: inherit; /* Fallback for IE <=7. */
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 6px; border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0; border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:last-child td:only-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px; border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

/***************************/

/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874705/is-it-possible-to-use-a-css-wildcard-in-the-middle-of-a-selector/6874731#6874731 */
/* #form\:tabView\:tabExceptions { */
/*
div[id=form\3AtabView\3AtabExceptions] {
    border: 5px solid black !important;
}
*/

/*
#form\:tabView\:tabExceptions {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
*/

[id="form\:tabView\:tabExceptions"] {
    border: 5px solid black;
}

/* ]]> */
</style>


<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header").corner();
});

/* ]]> */
</script></head><body>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/my-admin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/faces/index.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form" />
<div id="form:tabView" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-hidden-container ui-tabs-top tabView" style="border: 5px solid black !important;"><ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist"><li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#form:tabView:tab1">Home</a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#form:tabView:tabExceptions">Exceptions</a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#form:tabView:tab3">Search</a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#form:tabView:tab4">Process Management</a></li></ul><div class="ui-tabs-panels"><div id="form:tabView:tab1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
<form id="form:tabView:j_idt8" name="form:tabView:j_idt8" method="post" action="/my-admin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/faces/index.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="form:tabView:j_idt8" value="form:tabView:j_idt8" />
<span id="form:tabView:j_idt8:messages"></span><script id="form:tabView:j_idt8:messages_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','widget_form_tabView_j_idt8_messages',{id:'form:tabView:j_idt8:messages',sticky:false,life:6000,escape:true,msgs:[]});});</script><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-hidden-container accordionPanel" role="tablist"><h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Exception Volume Today</a></h3><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt10" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11" class="ui-datatable ui-widget ui-corner-all"><table role="grid"><thead><tr><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11:j_idt14" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" colspan="5"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>2013-02-04</span></div></th></tr><tr><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11:j_idt16" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span></span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11:j_idt17" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Outstanding</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11:j_idt18" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>>10 mins</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11:j_idt19" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>>20 mins</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11:j_idt20" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>>30 mins</span></div></th></tr></thead><tfoot></tfoot><tbody id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content"><tr data-ri="0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">ANF Items</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="1" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Dup Suspects</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="2" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Dup UOW</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">1</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">1</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="3" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Dup Transactions</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="4" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Large $ Suspects</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><script id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('DataTable','widget_form_tabView_j_idt8_j_idt9_j_idt11',{id:'form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt11'});</script></div><h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Exception Volume Yesterday</a></h3><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt31" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32" class="ui-datatable ui-widget ui-corner-all"><table role="grid"><thead><tr><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32:j_idt35" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" colspan="5"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>2012-08-29</span></div></th></tr><tr><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32:j_idt37" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span></span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32:j_idt38" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Outstanding</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32:j_idt39" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>>10 mins</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32:j_idt40" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>>20 mins</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32:j_idt41" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>>30 mins</span></div></th></tr></thead><tfoot></tfoot><tbody id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content"><tr data-ri="0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">ANF Items</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="1" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Dup Suspects</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="2" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Dup UOW</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="3" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Dup Transactions</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="4" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Large $ Suspects</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><script id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('DataTable','widget_form_tabView_j_idt8_j_idt9_j_idt32',{id:'form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt32'});</script></div><h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Volume by Image Channel</a></h3><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt52" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53" class="ui-datatable ui-widget ui-corner-all"><table role="grid"><thead><tr><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt56" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" colspan="2"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span></span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt57" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" colspan="2"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>2013-02-04</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt58" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" colspan="2"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>2012-08-29</span></div></th></tr><tr><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt60" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Image Channel</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt61" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Files Queued</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt62" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Files</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt63" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Number of Items</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt64" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Files</span></div></th><th id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53:j_idt65" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Number of Items</span></div></th></tr></thead><tfoot></tfoot><tbody id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content"><tr data-ri="0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">VIEX</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">1</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">29721</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="1" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">ULZ</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr><tr data-ri="2" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">Totals</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">1</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">29721</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">0</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><script id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('DataTable','widget_form_tabView_j_idt8_j_idt9_j_idt53',{id:'form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt53'});</script></div><h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Cart Item Exception Volume</a></h3><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt80" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>TODO</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Adjustment Volume</a></h3><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt83" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>TODO</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Balancing Totals</a></h3><div id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9:j_idt86" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>TODO</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><input type="hidden" id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9_active" name="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9_active" value="x" /></div><script id="form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('AccordionPanel','widget_form_tabView_j_idt8_j_idt9',{id:'form:tabView:j_idt8:j_idt9',multiple:true});</script><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="3488040969710992296:-5460895671588471169" autocomplete="off" />
</form></div><div id="form:tabView:tabExceptions" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><div id="form:tabView:tabView2" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-hidden-container ui-tabs-top tabView"><ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist"><li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#form:tabView:tabView2:tba12">ANF</a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#form:tabView:tabView2:tab22">Operator Locks</a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#form:tabView:tabView2:tab32">Single Item Duplicate Review</a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#form:tabView:tabView2:tab42">Multiple Item Duplicate Review</a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#form:tabView:tabView2:tab52">High Dollar Review</a></li></ul><div class="ui-tabs-panels"><div id="form:tabView:tabView2:tba12" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">

                tab 1

        </div><div id="form:tabView:tabView2:tab22" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">

                tab 2

        </div><div id="form:tabView:tabView2:tab32" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.                     Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><div id="form:tabView:tabView2:tab42" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.                     Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><div id="form:tabView:tabView2:tab52" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.                     Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div></div><input type="hidden" id="form:tabView:tabView2_activeIndex" name="form:tabView:tabView2_activeIndex" value="0" autocomplete="off" /></div><script id="form:tabView:tabView2_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('TabView','widget_form_tabView_tabView2',{id:'form:tabView:tabView2',effect: {name:'fade',duration:'normal'}});</script></div><div id="form:tabView:tab3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.                     Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><div id="form:tabView:tab4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.                     Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div></div><input type="hidden" id="form:tabView_activeIndex" name="form:tabView_activeIndex" value="0" autocomplete="off" /></div><script id="form:tabView_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('TabView','widget_form_tabView',{id:'form:tabView',effect: {name:'fade',duration:'normal'}});</script><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="3488040969710992296:-5460895671588471169" autocomplete="off" />
</form><div id="j_idt101" style="width:64px;height:64px;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px"><div id="j_idt101_start" style="display:none"><img id="j_idt102" src="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/images/loading.gif" alt="" /></div><div id="j_idt101_complete" style="display:none"></div></div><script id="j_idt101_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('AjaxStatus','widget_j_idt101',{id:'j_idt101'});widget_j_idt101.bindFacet('ajaxStart', 'start');widget_j_idt101.bindFacet('ajaxComplete', 'complete');</script>

<style>
/*
[id$=tabExceptions] {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
*/
</style></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post your generated form.

Comment: That would be quite hard... lots of nested JSF templates.

Comment: Run the code, open your browser, right click, view source, select form, copy, open this page, paste.

Comment: Just cut down to the smallest possible code snippet reproducing the problem? How is it hard to create a copy of the HTML output into a standalone HTML file and eliminate all unnecessary HTML as long as the problem still exhibits? By the way, have you considered just using classnames?

Comment: Attached the generated HTML... sorry, for some reason I thought you actually wanted the xhtml code. My mistake.

Comment: @BalusC I thought of using class names - I wanted to experiment with id's.

Comment: @BalusC I can see in firebug that `[id=form\:tabView\:tabExceptions] {
    border: 5px solid black;
}` is recognized for the element, but the style id overridden. The reason I prefer id over class is that id specificity is stronger. With class I depend on other selectors that are defined by primefaces. I also depend on the hierarchy of my element within the page. It might change later, and break the css. In my eyes, it's a bad design of CSS. Okay, they did not take into account id's like JSF creates. Any workaround???

Answer (score 0):

They all work fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/Sb32y/  something besides your selector is wrong.

```
<a id='form:tabView:tabExceptions' >No clue</a>

[id=form\:tabView\:tabExceptions]{
    color: grey;

}
[id$=tabExceptions]{
    background-color:blue
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work for me in a static page... but not in the xhtml page.

Comment: Please posted the generated form markup (at least the `<form id=..>` )