# Target dynamic IDs like #event_rules_attributes_0_interval, #event_rules_attributes_1_interval, etc. with CSS3

Tags: css, css-selectors

It is very convenient to style input tags using their IDs as they have more precedence weight than classes have.

For example, I have a default width for input.text elements in a specific container:

```
.details .metadata input.text { width: 200px; }
```

To change the width for a specific page, it's more convenient to use the ID instead of the long selector above:

```
#my_input { width: 150px; }
```

Now I have automatically generated input fields somewhere in my app (generated using `form_for` and `nested_attributes_for` in Ruby On Rails) which generates IDs like so:

```
#event_rules_attributes_0_interval
#event_rules_attributes_1_interval
#event_rules_attributes_2_interval
...etc...
```

and

```
#event_rules_attributes_0_count
#event_rules_attributes_1_count
#event_rules_attributes_2_count
...etc...
```

So I need to use an ID selector like `"begins with event_rules_attributes_"` AND `"ends with _count"` or `"begins with event_rules_attributes_"` AND `"ends with _interval"`. I know that there are the `[id$=]` and `[id^=]` matchers, but can they be combined somehow?

Comment: Here's another question that basically asks the same thing but is phrased quite differently: [Is it possible to use a CSS wildcard in the middle of a selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874705/is-it-possible-to-use-a-css-wildcard-in-the-middle-of-a-selector)

Answer (score 1):

Just found it out myself:

```
[id^='event_rules_attributes_'][id$='_interval'] { width: 150px; }
```

Seems a bit ugly, but works.

Comment: It's actually very normal. You just don't use attribute selectors nearly as often as you do IDs, classes or pseudo-classes so the syntax may seem strange, but you can combine any and all of these in virtually any order and it'll work.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to use these kind of selectors in productive enviroments, I use it only to apply hacks to 3rd parts softwares only when really needed. Would be better generate the code applying a _class_ to the elements.