# How to test that application.js is loaded asynchronously in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Using capybara, I want to test that the `application.js` file is loaded asynchronously. I have tried the following code

```
expect(page).to have_css('script[async="async"][src="/assets/application.js"]', visible: false)
```

but this does not work, because running the test in production mode, a digest is added, so the name of the file is something like `application-ae5fag34.js`. How do accomodate this?

Comment: Not exactly a dup, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874705/is-it-possible-to-use-a-css-wildcard-in-the-middle-of-an-attribute-selector should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `script[src^="/assets/application-"][src$=".js"][async="async"]` should work. However this should not be needed in the first place. Running tests on your production server is not exactly a good idea.

You should be running tests locally or on a CI server to catch bugs before they end up in production. Many test oriented gems are not meant for production and can lead to security holes.

Comment: This makes sense,  I will test it when I have  a chance before accepting.  I have edited my question to show that I meant running the test on my development server but in production mode.