# CSS id^= selector Issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a repeated group with a date field which as a button to select date in a calendar.

```
<button id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_1_cal_cal_img" class="btn calendarbutton" type="button">
```

Selector is

```
id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_0_cal_cal_img"
id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_1_cal_cal_img"
id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_2_cal_cal_img"
```

I have disabled my date field since the value is generated in another form.

I now would like to not display those repeated date buttons.

I tried something like that but it doesn't work:

```
[id^=form_59_].fabrikForm [id^="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_"]"_cal_cal_img" { display:none; }
```

Would appreciate your help and tips.

Comment: will this work or do you need to specify the `cal_cal_img` ending? `[id^="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_"] { display:none; }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6874705/483779

Comment: @Pangloss: You're correct. This one does seem to be a close enough dupe and so I'm closing it. But I had answered it before you seeing your comment and I feel that my answer does add a bit more value (in terms of what drawbacks it may have) in addition to the linked thread and so I am going to leave my answer also as-is and not delete it.

Comment: @Harry I like your answer, up voted already.

Comment: Thanks for that @Pangloss :) I'm leaving my previous comment as-is so that others don't end up asking about my reasoning for a separate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such *wildcard* selector which can help you match any single character in the middle of an attribute selector. Instead you can try one of the below. They are not 100% correct but can get you close to what you need (and are the closest that you could get to with pure CSS).

---

**First Selector in the demo:** (combination of starts with and ends with)

The first selector in the below demo will match when the `id` of the element ***starts with exactly the text*** `gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_` ***and it also ends with an exact text of*** `_cal_cal_img`.

One ***possible drawback of this selector*** (depending on the exact need is that ***this will also select elements that have the below as*** `id` as they also start and end with matching values:

`id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_10_cal_cal_img"`    `id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_100_cal_cal_img"`    `id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_10_a_cal_cal_img"`

---

**Second Selector in the demo:** (use only starts with and ignore the ends with)

The second selector in the demo  will ***select any element when the*** `id` ***starts with exactly the text*** `gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_`. This does not care about what is the ending part of the id.

The ***drawback with this one is*** that it will match the elements that have ids like the below also:

`id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co"`    `id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_1"`    `id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_2_cal_cal_imgs"`

---

**Demo with both the above mentioned options:**

```css
[id^="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_"][id$="_cal_cal_img"] {
  background: red;
}

/* use the above one or the below depending on your need */

[id^="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_"] {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_0_cal_cal_img" />
<input id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_1_cal_cal_img" />
<input id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_2_cal_cal_img" />
<input id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_2" />
<input id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_2_cal_img" />
<input id="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_2_cal_cal_imgs" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations and your time, solution which work nicely is :

     [id^="gprh_fabrik_user_registration_333_repeat___premier_rappel_co_"][id$="_cal_cal_img"]

Cheers, Marc

Comment: You're welcome @marcq. The question was a nice one too, I was just waiting to see if I understood you correctly before upvoting :)